# How to Export Graphics in MATLAB with exportdlg.m to SVG with embedding fonts?

Tags: matlab, svg, printing

Hello last_hope_community, ;)

I have tried several options of exporting, the standard export. Works well to SVG.

```
load patients
figure
tbl = table(LastName,Age,Gender,SelfAssessedHealthStatus,...
    Smoker,Weight,Location);
h = heatmap(tbl,'Smoker','SelfAssessedHealthStatus');

saveas(gcf,["test_heatp_save_svg.svg"],'svg') %no export style-> fonts gets embedded
%print(gcf,["test_heatp_print_pdf"],'-dpdf','-bestfit','-r0')
```

Saveas and print, but here is point 1. 
For setprinttemplate one can not adopt the styles from the exportsetup (hgexport and so on). Print has the very nicy opportunity of -bestfit which one can use with print to pdf(with print fonts are embedded automatically) and then to import in Inkscape to use as SVG. But when styles are adopted, by export manually to save it then as SVG within the exportdlg or with saveas, all fonts gets vectorpaths.

Is there a way to apply export styles automatically and then get an SVG File in which the fonts are embedded in SVG like in the upper code?
I have already checked if it is just a heatmap issue but it is not. Same with the following code, without export_style everything is great. But with export style everything gets to vector paths.

```
figure
plot(1:10000)
title('Hallo')

saveas(gcf,["test_simple_save_svg.svg"],'svg')
%print(gcf,["test_simple_print_pdf"],'-dpdf','-bestfit','-r0')
```

Best would be if anyone knows a way to apply exportstyles programatically and to then save as svg with embedded font, or apply exportstyles programmatically and then print to pdf with `-bestfit`,export as pdf would just embed the titles and not the TickLabels.
Additional print with bestfit is not always good because the result from the figure window varies from time to time a lot.

Thanks for help, it's annoying that export as svg makes paths from text that one cannot customize with other programms.

Comment: a few hours more testing... 
- export to svg transforms everything to paths (if just at one part the interpreter is latex)
- saveas (SVG) transforms everything with Latex Interpreter to paths (seems to be inevitable)
-hope is gone to get fonts embedded except latex interpreted text